# Jenkins downstream job build fails to initialize custom module

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to trigger a downstream job in jenkins. I tried generating the build syntax using the Pipeline Snippet Generator but the fails to provide parameter details of certain custom modules

I get these in the parameter section

```
*<object of type qui.controller.jenkins.acm.VersionParameterValue>, 
<object of type qui.controller.jenkins.acm.VersionParameterValue>, 
<object of type qui.controller.jenkins.acm.VersionParameterValue>, *
```

Now how can I find more details on this custom object? Any pointers?

I tried passing the arguments as string variables but the custom module does not seems to be accepting them.